# What does 'by' add to here?

Tags: meaning

What does 'by' add to here?

> They walked along **by** the old canal.

Answer (score 6):

To denote that they walked *adjacent* to the canal, rather than along it.

The phrase could alternatively be written:

> They walked along beside the old canal.

Comment: @Lambie The word *adjacent* in my answer is referring to the use of *by* (per the question), not the use of *along*. As you've correctly pointed out in your excellent answer, the use of *along* conveys a sense of ongoing leisurely strolling.

Comment: "Adjacent" is fine.

Comment: @BillJ "To denote they walked adjacent to the canal rather than along it": So that means that to walk adjacent to something and walk along something are different? I doubt that...they are the same thing.

Comment: @Lambie in the specific context of a canal, they do mean the same thing because there is normally no other way to walk along a canal. But if you replace "canal" with "road" there is a difference between walking along the road (which suggests actually on the road surface) and walking along beside the road (on the grass next to it, perhaps).

Comment: "Walk along the canal" sounds wrong to my (British English) ears, unless the canal is disused and dry. You can walk "along the tow-path", or "along the [canal] bank", but not "along the canal" itself, unless you can walk on water!

Comment: @alephzero or it's frozen! :)

Comment: @alephzero "Walk along the canal" sounds perfectly fine to my (American english) ears, so it's presumably a difference in dialect.

Answer (score 3):

They **|walked along|** in silence. [right, we say along so it doesn't sound so abrupt and provides the idea of the **ongoingnes**s of the walking, no canal]

They walked **|along the canal|**. [right, means: the path or banks that are located  beside the canal]

Here's the tricky bit: 
They walked **by the canal** and into town**. [they **passed it** during their walk].

As in: They walked **by the school** to the park. [they passed it and reached the park].

However, they walked along [in silence] by the field or canal means:

They walked along [ongoingness idea] by the field or by the canal with nothing else, means: they were parallel to it and not walking past it.

walk along = to stroll, to walk unhurriedly in an ongoing manner
walk by [some thing] = [go by or go past something]
BUT: walk by [some thing] can also mean: along or beside some thing.

But **both together** can only mean: to stroll or walk along the length of a thing: a road or path that goes by a field, a river, or other structure.

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget that [**by**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/by) is a preposition which, besides its other numerous meanings, basically means this:

> near or at the side of

So, what the quote in question is saying is that they were walking along the old canal and the walking process was happening very **close to it** (or, in other words, **by it**).

Comment: Yes, but the tricky bit is along and by together.